# How to pass table of objects using query string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios

i need to share some shipment information in my .NET Core 3.1 API project. I've designed an endpoint which returns a collection of objects which satisfy provided filtering conditions contained in SearchResultsDto object. The working principle of filtering mechanism is simple. On the client side, the user selects a property, and provides some value for it. The user may want to filter the table using one, two, or even more properties. So my controller method needs to take a collection of filters (pairs property-filter value) as a parameter. Here's my method, and Filter class definition:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SearchResultsDto>> GetShipmentAsync([FromQuery] ICollection<Filter> filters,
            [FromQuery] int page,
            [FromQuery] int pageCapacity,
            [FromQuery] DateTime dateTimeInfimum,
            [FromQuery] DateTime dateTimeSupremum,
            [FromQuery] bool withPodOnly) =>
                Ok(await QueryBus
                    .SendAsync<GetShipmentQuery, SearchResultsDto>(new GetShipmentQuery
                        {
                            Page = page,
                            PageCapacity = pageCapacity,
                            DateTimeInfimum = dateTimeInfimum,
                            DateTimeSupremum = dateTimeSupremum,
                            WithPodOnly = withPodOnly,
                            Filters = filters
                        }));

       public class Filter
       {
            public string PropertyName { get; set; }
            public string FilterValue { get; set; }
       }
```

How to correctly pass an array of Filter objects using the query string? Is it good approach to use query string for such a behavior? If not, how should i design my endpoint? How to serialize JavaScript objects, and send it using axios, in a proper way, using GET method?

I've already tried something like that:

```
https://localhost:44348/api/shipment?filters=[propertyName=materialReleaseReceipt&filterValue=WZ]&page=1&pageCapacity=4&dateTimeInfimum=2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z&dateTimeSupremum=2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z&withPodOnly=true
```

But it doesn't work. Filters collection is not parsed correctly.

Comment: It's entirely up to you, though I might add "not how you're doing it at the moment". GET request can have a body btw, and it would probably be cleanest to just send this as a block of JSON

Comment: I suggest you change the endpoint to `HttpPost` and parse the filters collection `[FromBody]` while keeping reading other parameters from querystring. Since GET requests can be cached by browser and sending the body as part of GET request can cause issues

Comment: Please elaborate on these "issues"

Comment: https://thecodebuzz.com/http-get-delete-request-body-guidelines/

Comment: Hi @Bulchsu, Did my answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi @mj1313 ! Thank you very much for your answer, i found it useful, and it helped me a little. While trying to find a solution i've grouped all the parameters, into single class. The header looks like "Task<ActionResult<SearchResultsDto>> GetShipmentAsync([FromQuery] GetShipmentRequest request)". GetShipmentRequest contain all the parameters, which my method required before. IN that case your solution is no working anymore - so i believe  "https://localhost:44385/weatherforecast?filters[0].Id=1&filters[1].Id=2" is quite better. Still i am very thankful for your effort. Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the data via query string, you can pass it like below,

`https://localhost:44385/weatherforecast?filters[0].Id=1&filters[1].Id=2`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just write the querystring like below:

```
https://localhost:44348/api/shipment?[0].propertyName=materialReleaseReceipt&[0].filterValue=WZ&page=1&pageCapacity=4&dateTimeInfimum=2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z&dateTimeSupremum=2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z&withPodOnly=true
```

For more details of model binding, you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections)